# How to I set a symbol inside the record separator of awk

Tags: awk, unicode, ascii, text-manipulation

How do I include symbols into the record separator of awk. I know the basic syntax like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[:.!]"}{if (tolower($0) ~ "$" ) print $0 }'
```

which will separate a single line into separate records based on ! . and : but I also want to include symbols like a green checkmark this `✅`. I am having trouble understanding the syntax, so I put it in like this

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[:.!\u2705]"}{if (tolower($0) ~ "$" ) print $0 }'
```

which doesnt seem to work.

Sample input is this:

```
✅  Team collaboration  ✅  Project organisation✅  SSO support✅  API Access✅  Priority Support
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regex with an alternation operator (`|`) because the character you want to split with consists of three separate UTF8 code units: `E2`, `9C` and `85`.

You can use

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[:.!]|\xE2\x9C\x85"} tolower($0) ~ "$"'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ED0rNJ):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='✅ Team collaboration ✅ Project organisation✅ SSO support✅ API Access✅ Priority Support'
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[:.!]|\xE2\x9C\x85"} tolower($0) ~ "$"' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
 Team collaboration 
 Project organisation
 SSO support
 API Access
 Priority Support
```

Note that `print $0` is a default action, no need to use it explicitly.